# Is it possible in snakemake to produce reports and the DAG images automatically?

Tags: snakemake

I would like to automatically produce the report and DAG images automatically after running the workflow in snakemake. Also I would like to create the report with a given name, e.g. specified in the `config.yaml`.

I cannot use the `snakemake` shell command inside the Snakefile which I would usually use to create the reports manually.

The code I would use for creating the report manually:

```
snakemake --report
```

The code for manually creating the DAG image:

```
snakemake --rulegraph | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
```

How can I do this in the Snakefile?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this but it looks pretty ugly to me. At the end of your Snakefile add:

```
onsuccess:
    shell(
        r"""
        snakemake --unlock
        snakemake --report
        snakemake --rulegraph | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
        """)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a "prettier" way? It can get even uglier if there is a config file or the snakefile is in another folder.

I've been trying to use `snakemake`s internal function `auto_report`, but it needs the DAG.
`from snakemake.report import auto_report; auto_report(dag, "reports/workflow.html")`

Do you know if it is possible to access the DAG internally?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @FGV comment, it can be done by using `auto_report` and providing the `dag` from `workflow.persistence`:

```
onsuccess:
    from snakemake.report import auto_report
    auto_report(workflow.persistence.dag, "report/report.html")
```

For the `dag` itself, you can export it to a text file and use `shell` to turn it to a pdf:

```
    with open("report/dag.txt","w") as f:
        f.writelines(str(workflow.persistence.dag))
    shell("cat report/dag.txt | dot -Tpdf > report/dag.pdf")
```

Note that it also works with the rules graph `workflow.persistence.dag.rule_dot()`